# How can I extract audio from a YouTube video?

Tags: audio, youtube

I would like to hear [Linus' talk about Git from youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XpnKHJAok8) on my way to work, which means I'm looking for an elegant way to extract .wav or .mp3 from a YouTube video.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

install [Youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/download.html) and  [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/)
then use the following commandline

Download the video

```
youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOURVIDEO
```

optionally use the `-k` flag to keep the video by default it deletes the video

Comment: love this way.... I was looking for something like this

Answer (score 10):

I have had success with [video2mp3.net](http://www.video2mp3.net/) – it is free and online!

Comment: can we trust this java applet?

Answer (score 7):

Add the [YouTube to MP3](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/11047) firefox add-on.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I used the [Online FLV convertor](http://vixy.net/) for this . Just give the url and select way of output you want .

[image]

Comment: My comment got deleted :S I was going to say that I tried this site earlier and gave link, however mp3 mode returned a 0 byte file and in AVI mode it had only pictures and no sound so I changed my link to the other one... Hopefully it will be fixed soon.

Comment: I had a similar problem as Wil with this and other sites too. The one that eventually worked for me was the one mentioned in the accepted answer.

Comment: This is not an online service anymore?  It's downloadable software Vixy Freecorder?

Answer (score 3):

```
mplayer x.flv -vo null -ao pcm
lame -V2 audiodump.wav talk.mp3
```

This will extract the audio in wav format and encode it to a VBR mp3 with lame.

Answer (score 2):

[Youtube Downloader](http://download.cnet.com/YouTube-Downloader/3000-2071_4-10647340.html)

It includes a video>audio converter.

Answer (score 2):

[video2mp3](http://www.video2mp3.net/index.php) comes in first, closely followed by [abcyoutube](http://www.abcyoutube.com/). Both cache popular videos, so there's 0 conversion time.

Answer (score 2):

In Safari 6 for OS X you can open the video from the web inspector and download it by pressing ⌥↩ on the location bar.

1. Enable the develop menu from the advanced preferences
2. Press ⌥⌘I and open or reload the page for the video
3. Double-click the videoplayback resource under the other folder
4. Focus the location bar and press ⌥↩ (option-return)

You can extract the audio without re-encoding with ffmpeg. It can be installed with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -acodec copy sound.aac
```

Answer (score 0):

[VDownloader](http://download.cnet.com/VDownloader/3000-2071_4-10888393.html?tag=mncol;1)

The reviewers didn't find anything against it.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer was originally intended to another question (that got merged into this question), where the user was the owner of the videos. This will not work if you don't own the videos yourself.**

1. Go to http://www.youtube.com/my_videos,
2. Click on the down arrow besides the video title
3. choose "download as MP4" (or other file format if applies)
4. use software installed on your computer to extract the audio from the file

(I don't own a mac, so I can't recommend a mac software for this final step).

Answer (score 0):

I don't trust the software like [vixy.net](http://vixy.net/), I think they track all my youtube activity.

[convert2mp3.net](http://convert2mp3.net) is my favorite now, they converted a rare video (so the video wasn't cached) to mp3 in less than one minute.

[listentoyoutube.com](http://listentoyoutube.com) needed ca. 5-6 minutes for the same video.

[video2mp3.net](http://video2mp3.net) needed more than two hours to extract the sound from the same video and they want to accept a java applet.

Answer (score 0):

You can **download directly only the (m4a) audio stream**.

- **SMTube** that comes with [SMPlayer](http://smplayer.sourceforge.net/) can search, list and play (and also download) Youtube videos, and has an option to select and edit players. Instead of a player a downloader (like uGet or IDM) can be set.

[image]

Take notice of the *Parameters* section for download, namely you may remove the `quiet` option and or set a different location for download.

Then, right-click a title in the list and select the downloader from the 'audio' option

[image]

---

- **Flashgot in Firefox**

After starting the youtube video in Firefox, right-click the Flashgot icon in toolbar and select only the audio stream by going to 'Available formats/DASH (separate audio and video tracks)'

[image]

and select the specific audio track.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://youtube-mp3-convert.org/youtube-mp3

I use this for collecting music, it may work for you. At the top of the page click the "Youtube to Mp3" link & enter the URL of the video you want just the sound from. Not 100% sure this will do what you want, would like to know if it does. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an open source package and command line tool for this in Go. By default,
it downloads video and audio, but you can download just audio like this:

```
youtube -v 0 youtube.com/watch?v=4XpnKHJAok8
```

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/89z/mech/youtube