# How can I download audio from YouTube videos?

Tags: linux, macos, audio, youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extract audio from youtube video](https://superuser.com/questions/19453/extract-audio-from-youtube-video)

I uploaded my sounds from GarageBand to YouTube and lost my original versions.

Now I need to get the sounds from YouTube. How can I get them?